# ThreadLocal causing memory leak even after cleanup?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, jvm, thread-local

I have a .war project which contains logic to set and reset a `ThreadLocal<String>` before and after receiving an HTTP call. From the tests I have run, I am pretty certain that both these actions are being performed correctly i.e. the ThreadLocal is being cleared soon after being set.
To test my project, I have a program that creates 10 threads and calls the server from these threads. After a 1 second wait, this process is repeated about 500 times. My goal is to monitor the heap storage being consumed and ensure there are no memory leaks.

Here are the important observations I made:

1. Calling the server when ThreadLocal is **not** being used: The heap size keeps on increasing the whole duration of the test and drops to the pre-test level after test-completion.
   [image: Heap usage without using ThreadLocal]
2. Calling the server when ThreadLocal is being used (set and then reset): After the calls to the server are completed, the heap retains most of the used up space. Hence, memory is leaking.
   [image: Heap usage with the use of ThreadLocal]

From what I know about the use of ThreadLocals, they might cause memory leaks if not reset properly. However, in my case, I am taking proper care to ensure that the ThreadLocal is being cleared (resetting the ThreadLocal in a `finally` block. With that said, what is it that could be causing this memory leak and how can I address it?

*P.S.: Here are some relevant code snippets from the project:*

```java
// Class for handling the ThreadLocal instances
public class EsStateStorage {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> outboundRequestThread = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static ThreadLocal<String> inboundRequestThread = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getOutboundRequestThread() {
        return outboundRequestThread.get();
    }

    public static void setOutboundRequestThread(String value) {
        outboundRequestThread.set(value);
    }

    public static void clearOutboundThreadStorage() {
        outboundRequestThread.remove();
    }

    public static String getInboundRequestThread() {
        return inboundRequestThread.get();
    }

    public static void setInboundRequestThread(String value) {
        inboundRequestThread.set(value);
    }

    public static void clearInboundThreadStorage() {
        inboundRequestThread.remove();
    }

}
```

```java
// Setting the ThreadLocal Value before making the HTTP call via rest-template
public TestData getData(...) throws{
    ...
    EsStateStorage.setOutboundRequestThread("TEST_VALUE");
    return restTemplate.exchange(...).getBody();
}
```

```java
// Resetting the thread storage in interceptors that capture all incoming/outgoing HTTP calls
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    try {
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        logOutboundCall(request, body, response);
        return response;
    } finally {
        EsStateStorage.clearOutboundThreadStorage();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have two `ThreadLocal<String>` instances and ten threads and think, they are responsible for 1GB memory consumption?

Comment: @Holger Probably not, but my concern is the absence of garbage cleaning when I am using `ThreadLocal` as can be seen from the graph. Between the two cases that I have mentioned in my question, the only change I made was to eliminate the use of ThreadLocal. Everything else was left the same. This leads me to the conclusion that ThreadLocal is somehow causing the retention of used up heap space. Hence my question

Comment: What happens if you continue testing when the heap size reached 1500MB? Besides that, it’s not clear how the code actually differs when you “don’t use ThreadLocal”. Normally, when you use them, they fulfill a purpose and the affected code has to change drastically when that feature is not available.

Comment: From the trend in the first graph, I would assume that the heap size would keep incrementing (beyond 1500MB) as long as I was continously making HTTP calls to the server. Also, the code change when I'm not using ThreadLocal is minimal. In the code snippets, I have attached above, to disable ThreadLocal usage, I simply made the methods of the `EsStateStorage` class do nothing on being invoked.

Comment: Well, the methods `getOutboundRequestThread()` and `getInboundRequestThread()` *return* something and if this class doesn’t store values anymore, they must return null or a made-up value, so in other words, the calling code may exhibit an entirely different behavior based on that. Regarding the behavior, don’t guess, just try it. If it keeps increasing, make a run with a forced heap size limit and configure the JVM to make a heap dump on out of memory error, then analyze the heap dump to find out where the leak is.

Answer (score 1):

You probably used `ThreadLocal<SomeCustomClass>` that prevents its Class Loader and hence the whole application to be garbage collected. If that is the case I suggest you use a custom `ThreadLocal` class, for example, https://github.com/codesinthedark/ImprovedThreadLocal that I created.